# How to normalise heat maps

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, normalization, heatmap

I am trying to normalise heat maps that are derived from a `2dhistogram`. I'd like the distributions to be relative, regardless of the amount of data points.

The attached code contains two sets of data. One has more x,y coordinates compared to the other. While the numbers are random is it possible to normalise these plots so the density represents the distribution not the frequency. Using the example below, x1-y1 will appear to have a lot more variation due to the amount of samples. Even though the underlying variation is similar to x2-y2

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np

fig, ((ax1, ax2)) = plt.subplots(1,2)

x1 = [random.randrange(1,101,1) for _ in range (10000)]
y1 = [random.randrange(1,101,1) for _ in range (10000)]

x2 = [random.randrange(1,100,1) for _ in range (1000)]
y2 = [random.randrange(1,100,1) for _ in range (1000)]

zi, xi, yi = np.histogram2d(x1, y1, bins=40, normed = False)
im = ax1.imshow(zi, interpolation = 'gaussian', origin = 'lower', cmap = 'jet')

zi, xi, yi = np.histogram2d(x2, y2, bins=40, normed = False)
im = ax2.imshow(zi, interpolation = 'gaussian', origin = 'lower', cmap = 'jet')
```

Can I normalise the rows by determining the maximum intensity or count in each bin and use that as a reference point and plot there other data from ranges 0 - 1?

Note: This isn't related to the above code but I'll attach examples to give a visual of what I'm hoping to achieve. My code produces the following images:

[image]

Whilst not reproducible with the above code, these images are produced as such:

```
C_f50,x,y,p = plt.hist2d(Con_F50X, Con_F50Y, bins = 40, range = np.array([(-85, 85), (4, 140)]))
ax9.imshow(C_f50.T, interpolation = 'gaussian', cmap = 'jet')

C_fmid,x,y,p = plt.hist2d(Con_FMIDX, Con_FMIDY, bins = 40, range = np.array([(-85, 85), (4, 140)]))
ax10.imshow(C_fmid.T, interpolation = 'gaussian', cmap = 'jet')

C_dmid,x,y,p = plt.hist2d(Con_DMIDX, Con_DMIDY, bins = 40, range = np.array([(-85, 85), (4, 140)]))
ax11.imshow(C_dmid.T, interpolation = 'gaussian', cmap = 'jet')

C_d50,x,y,p = plt.hist2d(Con_D50X, Con_D50Y, bins = 40, range = np.array([(-85, 85), (4, 140)]))
ax12.imshow(C_d50.T, interpolation = 'gaussian', cmap = 'jet')
```

The next set of images uses the `vmin` and `vmax` detailed by @filippo in the answers section.

[image]

As you can see the density has changed remarkably. the main difference is the `vmin/vmax` function. It gets these measures from the first plot (C_f50).

What I'm trying to understand is if there is another method to normalise the density of all plots from a separate point. The above used vmin/vmax from the first plot. But obviously if it's normalised from this plot the density won't change.

```
C_f50,x,y,p = plt.hist2d(Con_F50X, Con_F50Y, bins = 40, range = np.array([(-85, 85), (4, 140)]))
ax9.imshow(C_f50.T, interpolation = 'gaussian', cmap = 'jet')

C_fmid,x,y,p = plt.hist2d(Con_FMIDX, Con_FMIDY, bins = 40, range = np.array([(-85, 85), (4, 140)]))
ax10.imshow(C_fmid.T, interpolation = 'gaussian', cmap = 'jet',vmin=C_f50.min(), vmax=C_f50.max())

C_dmid,x,y,p = plt.hist2d(Con_DMIDX, Con_DMIDY, bins = 40, range = np.array([(-85, 85), (4, 140)]))
ax11.imshow(C_dmid.T, interpolation = 'gaussian', cmap = 'jet', vmin=C_f50.min(), vmax=C_f50.max())

C_d50,x,y,p = plt.hist2d(Con_D50X, Con_D50Y, bins = 40, range = np.array([(-85, 85), (4, 140)]))
ax12.imshow(C_d50.T, interpolation = 'gaussian', cmap = 'jet',vmin=C_f50.min(), vmax=C_f50.max())
```

Does any of this make sense?

Comment: Best to achieve what exactly? What is the criterion?

Comment: I've updated the question. Does that make sense or should I attach a image displaying the issue more clearly?

Comment: `imshow` already does local normalization by default, do you want to normalize globally? i.e. use the same normalization for all the subplots?

Comment: Yes @filippo. I'd like the the plots to use the same normalisation.

Comment: What normalization are you talking about? There is a `density` argument (which should be used instead of `normed`). In how far is this not what you're after?

Comment: You cannot alter the density. Not sure what you mean though.

Comment: I've made the question a lot more convoluted and i'll clean it up later. I just wanted to show my code. These plots use the same xy data. Because there's not much data the density isn't apparent. But when I use `vmin` and `vmax` it scales or normalises the density.

Comment: I just wanted to know what that normalising function does. Also if I wanted to 'normalise' all plots, how would I do that. If I use vmin and vmax on the first plot it won't have the same affect obviously.

Comment: @Maxibon if I understood correctly what you want you should stack all your `C_*` histograms, find `min` and `max` and use those as `vmin`, `vmax` for all the plots. Otherwise using `imshow`  to compare distributions can be quite misleading as it does per-image normalization under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood the question completely. The attached plot has no apparent relation with the code you posted.

You could precompute your histogram, find minimum and maximum values and use them for normalization with `vmin` and `vmax` `imshow` parameters.

E.g.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# gen 9 2d gaussian samples and histogram
data = np.random.normal(size=(9, 10000, 2))
zidata = np.asarray([np.histogram2d(row[:,0], row[:,1], bins=40)[0] for row in data])

# plot 
gridspec = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(3,3)
for zi, gs in zip(zidata, gridspec):
    ax = plt.subplot(gs)
    ax.imshow(zi, interpolation='gaussian', vmin=zidata.min(), vmax=zidata.max())
    ax.axis("tight")
plt.show()
```

By default imshow normalizes your data with [Normalize](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize) which basically applies a simple linear transformation like:

```
vmin = img.min()
vmax = img.max()
return (img - vmin)/(vmax - vmin)
```

You can alter its behavior setting `vmin` and `vmax` manually, like in this example which sets them to the global extrema among all the subplots.

Alternatively if you need more control you can set `norm=matplotlib.colors.NoNorm` and normalize your data yourself so that it maps correctly to a matplotlib colormap.

Comment: Thanks @filippo. That's changed the density. Could yo please give more info on what that does. Or point me in the right direction. I can't find anything other than some seaborn plots